# Where was Qiskit-Textbook downloaded?

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit

I've installed Qiskit-textbook by `pip install git+https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook.git#subdirectory=qiskit-textbook-src`. But I don't know where is it downloaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That command installs the Qiskit Textbook *package*, which is a Python package containing some of the problems and widgets used in the textbook. You can see the location of an installed package using `pip show <package>`:

```
pip show qiskit-textbook
```

output:

```
Name: qiskit-textbook
Version: 0.1.0
Summary: A collection of widgets, tools and games for using along
  the Qiskit Textbook. See the textbook and a list of contributors at qiskit.org/textbook
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: Qiskit Team
Author-email: hello@qiskit.org
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: ipython, matplotlib, numpy, qiskit, ipywidgets
Required-by:
```

From which I can see my package is installed at `/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages`.

If you want to download the Jupyter notebooks (i.e. the pages of the textbook), you can do this from the [Github page](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook). There is a big green button labelled "code" if you click it, you can either get the link to clone it through git, or [download it as a `.zip`](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/archive/refs/heads/master.zip). All the pages are inside the "content" folder.

Comment: I had this same problem once, and felt qiskit's naming of this was a little vague, but you can see in the URL that this directory has tools etc in it, not the textbook content. https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/tree/main/qiskit-textbook-src/qiskit_textbook